# How to return large data through GWT RPC

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, objectify

I am facing an issue while retrieving large data through GWT RPC , I have used Objectify to load data.
I am working on application which is build on gwt-2.6.1 and appengine -1.9.6.

Can someone help/suggest some other way to load large data.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and let us know what is the issue that you are experiencing with possibly some reproducable code?

Comment: when i am loading large data ,appengine gives me Error code-203 which is basically time out .

Comment: Hi @AnilPal Could you please elaborate a little more? Are you using GAE Standard or Flex? Are you using another GCP products moreover Datastore? This error might be related with your quotas (both, AppEngine and Datastore), have you take a look into them? All this information would be very helpful to address the issue.